# .Net MVC and Kendo - conditionally bind div based on selected option

Tags: asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, knockout.js

I am *almost* there!

I would like to show a specific div based on the selected value.

For example, if selected value = "Option1" is chosen, then show corresponding div.

I've tried the following in the data-bind:

data-bind="if"selectedValue() === 'Option1'"

I am successfully able to use data-bind="visible" selectedValue" to toggle, but both divs show. I would like to get at the object property itself.

Here's the code:

```
<select data-bind=", options: availableValues, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedValue, optionsCaption: 'Select One'"></select>

<div data-bind="if:selectedFieldType() === 'Option1' ">
        @Html.Partial("_Edit" + this.Model.Type)
</div>

<div data-bind="if:selectedFieldType() === 'Option2' ">
        @Html.Partial("_Add" + this.Model.Type)
</div>

$(function () {

        var testModel = {
            availableValues: ko.observableArray(@Html.Json(Model.SelectedValueOptions)),
            selectedValue: ko.observable(null))
        };

        testModel.value= ko.dependentObservable(function () {
            if (this.selectedValue()) {
                return this.selectedValue().Val;
            }
        }, testModel);

        var tryGetValue = $.grep(testModel.availableSelectedValues(), function (item) {
            return item.Val === '@Model.Value';
        })[0] || null;

        testModel.selectedValue(tryGetValue);

        ko.applyBindings(testModel, $('#general-section')[0]);
    });
```

Comment: How is the objects in your `availableValues` look like? You probably need to use the `optionsValue` on your select because otherwise your `selectedValue` will contain a complex object and not the string `Option1` and `Option2`...

Comment: it works - http://jsfiddle.net/GCf4L/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Artem's comment, I was able to fix it - I was referencing if:value()...and needed to reference the value referenced in the model as opposed to the name I used in the binding parameters (e.g. testModel.value - value was what I needed to reference (in my case that was xyzType as opposed to the generic term "value" that was used in the data-bind options.